# Auto-resizing textarea is bumpy + highlighting parentheses

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, syntax-highlighting, parentheses

I am trying to create a simple textarea that will expand according to the text. I also want to syntax highlight parentheses. This all works *fairly* well but is not perfect. I am doing this with a hidden `<pre>` in the background that holds all the values I need to resize the area properly. The hidden `<pre>` also holds all the colors for my parentheses.

First off, the resizing of the textarea is bumpy. For some reason the text jumps up when you hit enter. It's easy enough to reproduce. Just enter something like

```
test
test
```

And then hit enter, you'll see what I mean.

Secondly the problem with highlighting the parentheses. If I insert something quite massive, like: `)))))))))))))))))))(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((` the coloring gets all messed up. I have no idea why.

Something even crazier that reproduces the bug is

```
 )))))))))))))))))))((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((()))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Any help is appreciated, one problem or the other!

Here's a link to the fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Axvgf/41/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the question. Is your code public domain, or anything? Would you mind if I create a github project for it (with full credits to you of course)? (BTW, I asked the same question to Ertug)

Answer (score 1):

You should not calculate Depth if parenthesis are not matching. For instance

```
)))(())
```

depth should be,

```
undefined, undefined, undefined, 1, 2, 2, 1
```

or

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1
```

Just color non-matching parenthesis red and matching parenthesis by their level.

---

Text jumps up when you press enter because you ignore empty line at the bottom of text. Your should add its height too.

**css**

```
.defaultEm:{
  font-size:1em;
  position:absolute;
  line-height:1;
  padding:0;
  visibility:hidden
}
```

**script**

```
function getDefaultFontSize(pa){
     pa= pa || document.body;
     var who= document.createElement('span');
     who.className= 'defaultEm';
     who.appendChild(document.createTextNode('M'));
     pa.appendChild(who);
     var fs= [who.offsetWidth, who.offsetHeight];
     pa.removeChild(who);
     return fs;
}
```

and

```
var newHeight = $(newId + " pre").height() + getDefaultFontSize()[1]; //adding a height of line
```

Fixing height: http://jsfiddle.net/ACF8e/

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the jsfiddle. Is it public domain, or anything? Would you mind if I create a github project for it (with full credits to you of course)?

Comment: Bump @Ertug. See comment above.